# Automatic Maven project changes resolution with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

The problem: we have dozens of Maven sub-projects (managed by m2eclipse) in our 3-level POM tree and people keep adding and removing some of them on a bi-weekly basis. The problem is further complicated by a fact that not all newly added projects result in compile-time error when they are missing. The could end up not being dropped into OSGi container since people forget to import them properly and Eclipse for some reason doesn't know about their existence automatically.

Currently, people have to watch some mailing list and whenever there is such an event, they have to go and either manually invoke import wizard for the very root POM and add missing projects or manually remove some of the not needed ones. Moving/renaming is a combination of removing/adding.

That all is very error prone and we would like to automate/simplify the process somehow.

Ideally, we would like to have the following workflow:
1) sync
2) fire Eclipse
3) Some hook to trigger which would analyze developer's workspace against latest POM tree (the very root POM is fixed and known)
4) There should be some button somewhere which would be:
- green, if everything is all-right
- red, if not
Clicking it should automatically remove not needed projects (and update Eclipse internals) and add the new ones (some sort of invoking import wizard in a silent mode).

Is it possible with the existing functionality? Or would we have to somehow extend m2e? Any other solutions???

Any help would be very appreciated!

P.S.

We're aware that this type of problem we have is probably due to badly designed project structure. However, it's not easy to get that fixed while running on tight release cycles. So, we need an interim solution.

Answer (score 1):

This smells to me that you're fixing a wrong problem. I doubt something like this would be supported out-of-the-box in m2e - unless one day it becomes best practice to put each type in it's own module. After some time project modules should stabilize, and reflect architecture which can change but not frequently (major versions only). If it changes too frequently then not enough thought has been put into design decisions. Consider splitting projects into multiple sub-projects which one can checkout/clone and work independently on.

When syncing changes just check if there were modules added/deleted - and if so, after sync just logically remove and then import back existing maven projects.